# Add form fields programmatically to Wagtail Form

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a model which subclasses `AbstractEmailForm`..

I can create a new instance with:

```
new_page = LanderPage(body='body text here', title='Test sub page', 
     slug='testsub', to_address='j@site.com',from_address='j@site.com', subject='new inquiry')
```

This works, but it produces a form without fields. I am not sure how to create the form fields using this structure, such as the form field for name and email address.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

For reference, this is the page being created:

```
class LanderPageFormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('LanderPage', related_name='form_fields')


class LanderPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),

    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form fields are accessible through the relation `new_page.form_fields` - check [the definition of AbstractFormField in the Wagtail source](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/d302bea68c6b2b8c8d580154bf3ec03bd1a7f8c1/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py#L79-L109) for the fields to supply. For example:

```
new_page.form_fields = [
    LanderPageFormField(label="Name", field_type="singleline", required=True),
    LanderPageFormField(label="Email", field_type="email", required=True),
]
```

(Since the relation is defined as a [ParentalKey](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster#django-modelcluster), it's possible to attach these to the object before saving `new_page`, which wouldn't be possible with a standard Django ForeignKey.)